# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-deployment

I'm trying to integrate webpack with my react project and I get the following error message.

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.
```

I tried to find some answers on here but to no avail. It looks like the problem is stemming from my index.js page where I try to render the entire app

```
ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
"name": "app",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@material-ui/core": "^4.4.2",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.4.1",
"axios": "^0.19.0",
"babel-core": "^6.26.3",
"material-ui": "^0.20.2",
"react": "^16.10.2",
"react-activity": "^1.2.2",
"react-dom": "^16.10.2",
"react-dropzone": "^10.1.10",
"react-redux": "^7.1.1",
"react-responsive-carousel": "^3.1.51",
"react-router": "^5.1.2",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
"react-router-flux": "^1.0.0",
"react-scripts": "3.1.1",
"react-tap-event-plugin": "^3.0.3",
"redux": "^4.0.4",
"redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
"redux-promise": "^0.6.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
"serve": "^11.2.0",
"superagent": "^5.1.0"
},
"scripts": {
"start": "PORT=8080 react-scripts start",
"build": "webpack --env.API_URL=https://neighbor-hood.herokuapp.com --config 
webpack.config.build.js",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
"extends": "react-app"
},
"browserslist": {
"production": [
  ">0.2%",
  "not dead",
  "not op_mini all"
],
"development": [
  "last 1 chrome version",
  "last 1 firefox version",
  "last 1 safari version"
]
},
"devDependencies": {
"webpack": "^4.39.1",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
}
}
```

Here is my webpack.config.build.js file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack'); 
module.exports = (env) => {
const envKeys = Object.keys(env).reduce((prev, next) => {
prev[`process.env.${next}`] = JSON.stringify(env[next]);
return prev;
}, {});

module:{
    rules:[{
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$|jsx/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
    }]
}


return {
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin(envKeys)
]
};
};
```

Any my .babelrc file if necessary:

```
.babelrc
{
"presets": ["env", "react","@babel/preset-env"],
"plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties"
]
}
```

Here is my index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Main from './Main';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';


ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Not sure what this means now ... (may have answered it)

[image]

Comment: You need to give some details about where that error is taking place, which file type is it referring to?

Comment: @logos_164 I edited my post above. The problem is coming from my index.js file where I try to render my entire app --> ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root'));

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is right here.  There is a carriage return, or new line, after `--config`.

```
"build": "webpack --env.API_URL=https://neighbor-hood.herokuapp.com --config 
webpack.config.build.js",
```

Try this.

```
"build": "webpack --env.API_URL=https://neighbor-hood.herokuapp.com --config webpack.config.build.js",
```

Comment: your first solution is exactly what I have ..?

Comment: You have a carriage return in there. You need to remove that or add the `" + "` to concat the lines.

Comment: when i copy/paste your first answer i get the same error message. the second one throws a 'Unexpected token + in JSON'

Comment: Oh, well that may not have been the answer to solve your problem. It's just a problem I noticed in your code when I copied/pasted it in my vscode window to format. I'll update answer to remove second option. There may be more to your problem. Do you mind also posting your index.js?

Comment: I just added it. and thanks for your help with this

Comment: Please check my post again. I borrowed a solution from a previous stackoverflow post and it appeared to work. It looks like it builds properly however nothing happens (unlike when i run 'npm run start' and it automatically opens my browser and launches my site)

Comment: Did you update the code in your question to reflect what you changed? The output you posted looks good. Can you hit `localhost:3000`?